# Microsoft Azure Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: powershell, azure

I am attempting to configure my first Azure site-to-site vpn. I have followed the instructions here

https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-create-site-to-site-rm-powershell.md

However, the connection shows disconnected.

I was wondering if I need to create an address on an actual local vpn device to make it work?

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure the question you are asking. Could you please be more specific with the configuration you are using, the topology you are trying to set up, and where you think the problem may be?

Comment: Can you detail your configuration please? what Azure elements have you create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your end point is compatible: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices/ you can follow the Azure documentation. Once you have done the Azure config, you can download the VPN terminating config from within Azure. Load that config document onto your VPN router. I have successfully used this documentation (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal/ ARM or Classic) to successfully setup site to site VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Your local VPN Device will need to be configured with the public ip address of the Virtual Network Gateway. If you did not configure this then it is normal that the connection shows as disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you need a VPN device on the other end of the tunnel? because it sounds like you're actually asking if you need a VPN device on the other end of the tunnel :)

Yes, VPN Site-to-Site must have a local VPN device/service that allows the VPN session to be created and for data to be routed in between.